# Extract field from Javascript object in google apps script

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I am very new at this and the answer is probably very simple, but please help.

I get the following returned from a query, this is a `jsonParse` of the result

```
{"totalSize":1,
"done":true,
"records":
    [{"attributes": 
    {
        "type":"Account",
        "url":"/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Account/001C0000012Z8Y5IAK"
    },
    "Id":"001C0000012Z8Y5IAK"
    }] 
}
```

How do I extract the `Id` at the end into a variable when `totalSize = 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

objectName.records[0].Id will do the trick. Increment records index appropriately.

Sample -

```
var sforceResponse = {"totalSize":1,"done":true,"records":[{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Account/001C0000012Z8Y5IAK"},"Id":"001C0000012Z8Y5IAK"}]}

sforceResponse.records[0].Id //this variable contains the Id.
```

Comment: I get "TypeError: Cannot read property "Id" from undefined." Here is my code

Comment: var fields = "Id";
    var soql = "SELECT "+fields+" FROM Account WHERE Site_ID__c = '"+ siteID +"'LIMIT 100";
    var queryUrl = instanceUrl + "/services/data/v21.0/query?q="+encodeURIComponent(soql);
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl, { method : "GET", headers : { "Authorization" : "OAuth "+accessToken } });
    var queryResult = Utilities.jsonParse(response.getContentText());
    
    if (queryResult["totalSize"]=1) {
      var acctId = queryResult.records[0].Id;
    } else {
      var acctId = "NotFound";
    }

Comment: First thing I noticed is that you want to change this line - queryResult["totalSize"]=1 to be queryResult["totalSize"]===1. The code as is will always be true as its just an assignment and the 2nd version will actually do the comparision. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you very much.  I assumed I had a syntax error and never thought about this as a data error.  Problem solved.

Comment: Great. Glad to hear. Mark this as accepted so that the next person knows what fixes the issue.